# Conditional Treatment Necessary while Printing answer with MOD?

Tags: c++11, math, dynamic-programming

While Subtraction  my code with

```
((ans%m) - (sum_of_divisors%m))%m
```

was judged incorrect
but Apparently This statement solved it all

```
(ans>sum_of_divisors)?ans - sum_of_divisors : m - sum_of_divisors + ans;
```

What are other operations that require such steps and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a % m` can be negative, if `a` is negative.
A workaround would be: `(a % m + m) % m`, or, in your example `((ans - sum_of_divisors) % m + m) % m`.

Comment: Is this mathematically valid , is (a-b)%m  equivalent to (m-b+a) when a-b is negative ? If not then why is it used to judge answers in Competitive Programming Sites ?